# Remember me functionality - simplest way

Tags: scala, authentication, playframework, playframework-2.2

I've implemented a simple authentication system as it's described in the play's documentation. That being said, there is no mention about remember me functionality and how to implement it. Searching in the Internet didn't give me any relevant result.

What I want is a **simple** way to do so. I don't need any plugins or libraries for this for sure. How do I do this?

**update:**

```
addForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
  failure => BadRequest(views.html.session add failure),
  success => Redirect(routes.Account.index())  withSession "email" -> success._1

)
```

Comment: [Cookies?](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaSessionFlash)

Comment: @ggovan, how do I set the time to expire for the cookie?

Comment: Set [`maxAge`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Cookie) when you create or copy the cookie.

Comment: @ggovan, but I don't use cookie directly, look at my update.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Play documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaSessionFlash)

> There is no technical timeout for the Session. It expires when the user closes the web browser.

This can be overriden in `conf/application.conf` by setting:

```
session.maxAge=....
```

It is not possible to override this on a per session basis.
This applies to all session used by this application as shown by [the source.](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Http.scala#L574)

---

An alternative approach is to use cookies. To use cookies as you use the session in your example (but with the option to set the maxAge) you can do the following:

```
def signText(key: String, value: String): String = {
  val text = key + "=" + value
  Crypto.sign(text) + "-" + text
}

val maxAge: Int = ???

addForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
  failure => BadRequest(views.html.session add failure),
  success => Redirect(routes.Account.index()) withCookies Cookie("PLAY_SESSION",sign("email",success._1),maxAge)
)
```

Comment: will it work the same as `withSession "email" -> success._1` does?

Comment: _will it work the same?_  Well, no, that's the point; sessions can't do what you want them to here. Cookies are used in a very similar manner to sessions (a session is a type of cookie). Look at the documentation about cookies and sessions, and then just experiment.

Comment: I know how they work. I mean, is the only difference between your code and mine that your code will expire in `maxAge`, whereas mine once an user closes the browser?

Comment: Try? No, you first give me the guarantee that no harm will happen and, in particular, my computer won't explode by itself.

Comment: actually, this doesn't work because my code saved the email in the cookie **along with** the long random key (`"878c0b6495fcc815581ee02fa320717136d30a70-email=test1%40mail.com"`) (which is added automatically by Play) and this cookie is called play_session. Whereas yours just creates the cookie containing email with maxAge. That means, anybody might well compromise it easily. **I need to set  maxAge for play_session cookie**

Comment: There we go, you can set it through the configuration file.

Comment: the issue is not to set it per se, the issue is to set it dynamically. how would I set it in the configuration file dynamically depending whether the checkbox "Remeber me" is checked or not (when an user is logging in)? That's not possible. Moreover, the config file is the application based, whereas this checkbox is user based.

Comment: My answer now shows that you cannot set the maxAge, on a per-session basis, using Play. You can do it on cookies, and you can also sign cookies in the way that the session was signed. I hope this helps.